# Developing Logic for node js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, nodejs-stream

I am HTML developer ,  I recently started learning Node.js ,as I wanted to be backend developer ,

As I am new to the backend technology and javascript so I just wanted to ask do basic programs like odd even , pattern Question , or other similar type question will help to develop my logic , 
or 
I should directly start working on Projects and by doing projects my logic will Automatically Improve

Comment: You can learn using tutorial and after that make some demo and start with project

Comment: This is not a place for these type of questions. Quora or reddit are better places for asking these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are familiar with the algorithms and data structure, you just need to learn the new syntax which JS offers. Logic is not related to any language. There are plenty of tutorials available online which can teach you the basics of javascript. 
For your reference: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:
I recommend you to start with a basic Node.js tutorial, for example: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/

After this, you should take a more complex tutorial, a really good one:
https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-nodejs-developer-course-2/

After these you can try and develop your own backend, based on any of your idea.